# Check if email is @exampleemail.com

Tags: javascript, php, html, email

On my e-commerce website invoice files are created with a javascript file. I want to add 2 other files (7 pages) to this file. So after the invoice page ends the script would start. But i want the other pages to be added if the user has 
 a email that ends with @exampleemail.com.
I would have to import the email but I don't want to display it on the invoice.
So I would put this variable somewhere where it would not be printed to the invoice page.

```
let exmail = {user.Email} // I already have a php file with the variable
```

Now I would like to check if the email (exmail variable) has @exampleemail.com in it.

Hope you have enough information to help me with my problem.

Edit: I already know how I would write the code. Just want more opinions, maybe some are better that mine. And I just wrote a example code, the {} part is working because its connected to my php backend.

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [strpos](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strpos.php) in php:

```
<?php
$emailPattern   = '@exampleemail.com';
$pos = strpos($exmail, $emailPattern);

if ($pos === false) {
    //Invalid email
} else {
    //valid email
}

?>
```

Or javascript [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf):

```
var isValidEmail = exmail.indexOf('@exampleemail.com');
if (isValidEmail !== -1){
//true valid
} else {
//false email
}
```